# Loading Parsed XML data into simpleListAdapter?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, saxparser, listadapter

I'm writing 3 classes/activities that I hope to (eventually) be able to load parsed XML data into a simpleListAdapter, using stock android layouts.

My strategy is that Activity A: Starts SAX parser, loads handler, retrieves ArrayList> from Activity C, and Loads the ArrayList into a simpleListAdapter.

Activity B is the handler (which I know works because I've used it before, no problem there).

Finally Activity C contains the methods that return Strings, which are given values by the handler, then loads these strings into a ArrayList> that is sent to Activity A via intent.

But all that comes up is a black screen.

The test XML site I'm using is http://www.google.com/ig/api?weather=Boston+Massachusetts"

Here's the code for Activity A + C (I know the handler works).

Activity(A):

```
public class xmlparser extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {

static final String XMLsite = "http://www.google.com/ig/api weather=Boston+Massachusetts";


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  





@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
    try{
        URL website = new URL(XMLsite);
        //getting xmlreader to parse data
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
        HandlingXMLStuff doingWork = new HandlingXMLStuff();
        xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list =(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("arraylist");

        String[] from = { "name", "purpose" };
        int[] to = { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);


        }catch(Exception e){

    }
}
```

Activity(C):

```
package com.school;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class XMLDataCollected extends Activity{
 /** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, xmlparser.class);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = buildData();
    intent.putExtra("arraylist", list);
    startActivity(intent);
}

int temp = 0;
String city = null;

public void setCity(String c){
    city = c;

}
public void setTemp(int t){
    temp = t;
}


private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> buildData() {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    list.add(putData(city, "temp"));
    list.add(putData("city", "temp"));
    list.add(putData("city", "temp"));
    return list;
}

private HashMap<String, String> putData(String name, String purpose) {
    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item.put("name", name);
    item.put("purpose", purpose);
    return item;
}
}
```

Any advice would help.

P.S. I've used this XML procedure before to load the data into a textview, so I know that its able to at least parse the XML tags and set them on the methods in Activity C, then retrieve and set the Strings in a textview, but my ultimate goal is to be able to load the information into a simpleListAdapter.

Thanks

Comment: Your code is a mess. You don't need 3 activities just to parse a xml from a site and show it in a `ListView`.

Comment: [Here](http://goo.gl/OIzTo) is a scenario you need to follow for your problem. This is not a XML parsing demo but just go through the steps screen follows.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, your code is tragic. You don't need two activities for this opteration. Instead consider an AsyncTask or a Service with the XMLParser staying in Activity one. What Activity one is then responsible for, is starting the AsyncTask or Service and retrieving (parsing) its data as it becomes available.

```
public class ActivityOne extends Activity {
    private static final String ADDRESS = "...";
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        new FetchDataTask(ADDRESS).execute();
    }


    private class FetchDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private URL mWebsite;
        private ArrayList<???> mListActivityContent;

        public FetchDataTask(String address) {
            mWebsite = new URL(address);
        }

        @Override public void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            //getting xmlreader to parse data
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            HandlingXMLStuff doingWork = new HandlingXMLStuff();
            xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);
            xr.parse(new InputSource(mWebsite.openStream()));
            /*
             * Now, you are going to want other parsing and
             * array building stuff here. Looking at your code,
             * I can't figure out how the XMLDataCollected
             * Activity is used, sorry, so you will have to tweak
             * this to accomodate it.
             */
        }

        @Override public void onPostExecute(Void voids) {
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ActivityOne.this,
            list, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, from, to);

            ActivityOne.this.setListAdatper(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm obviously new to android and parsing.  I've look through 4 examples on parsing xml in android including the google developer example which contains 4 classes.  Each one takes a different approach and establishing a Parser, Handler, and Datacollected class was the only the one that made the most sense to me so that is why I have kept this model.  If you know of any tutorials/examples on xml parsing to a cutom list view it would be very nice/constructive for you to share. Thanks

Comment: @Bob, I posted something similar to how I would accomplish this. Take it with a grain of salt, I had to assume a few things. Hope it helps! :) PS: I didn't mean to come off as harsh, but somethings just needed to stated plainly; best way to learn IMHO.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot Aedon, I haven't had much time to try out your suggestion but I did run across this tutorial that I think might help others starting the xml parsing path: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample example of listing country names and country code from java local into listview using simpleAdapter 
SimpleAdapter In Detail Understanding @ http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2014/06/simpleadaper-bind-hashmap-listview.html

Another Example Parsing XML and show into ListView Using SimpleAdapter @ http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2015/03/android-sax-xml-parser-http.html

XML Layout for items of listview

file : list_items.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="horizontal"
   android:padding="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:textSize="18dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/code"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

file : MainActivity.java

```
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Locale;
 import android.app.ListActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.widget.ListAdapter;
 import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> countries;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] locales = Locale.getISOCountries();

    countries = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    for (String countryCode : locales) {
        Locale obj = new Locale("", countryCode);

        HashMap<String, String> country = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String country_name = obj.getDisplayCountry();
        String country_code = obj.getCountry();

        country.put("name", country_name);
        country.put("code", country_code);

        countries.add(country);

    }
    //  keys of hashmap
    String[] from = { "name", "code" };

    // view id's to which data to be binded
    int[] to = { R.id.name_id, R.id.code_id };

    //Creating Adapter
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, countries,
            R.layout.list_items, from, to);

    //Setting Adapter to ListView
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

}